# 'NA' handling in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a dataframe with name,age fieldname,name column has **missing value**  and **NA** when i  read the value using pd.read_excel,**missing value**  and **NA** become NaN,how can i avoid this issue.
this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['Tom', '', 'NA','', 'Ricky',"NA",''],'Age':[28,34,29,42,35,33,40]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel("test1.xlsx",sheet_name="test")
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_excel("./test1.xlsx")
```

[image: getting this][image: expected one]

Comment: maybe passing `dtype={'Name':str}` to `read_excel`.

Comment: What is the issue exactly? What you want to do with NaN values? If you want to drop NaN values you can use `df.dropna()`.

Comment: look 2nd and 5th column i names it **NA** , but i get  **NaN**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this, just set the `keep_default_na` to False:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test1.xlsx', keep_default_na=False)
```